# how to pass variable inside html href in the view in mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

i want to pass dynamic imei number , instead of static imei. i want to pass

```
obj[i].DeviceImei
```

inside the href tag at the place of 1009 for the google map marker info window view more option.

```
 var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                                        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                                        "</div>" +
                                        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                                        "<p><b>Location: " + obj[i].location + "<br>"
                                        + "\n" +"IMEI: " + obj[i].DeviceImei +"<br>"
                                                                                                                 
                                        + "\n" + "PRV Trip: " + obj[i].PRV_T + "<br>"
                                        +'<a href="http://hostname/1009">' +
                                        "View More" +
                                        "</p>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                        "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scape quotes with `\"`, so in your case it would be:

```
+'<a href=\"http://hostname/' + obj[i].PRV_T + '\">' +
```